# How can I change the font in radio buttons that I am creating from a string array?

Tags: android, radio-button

My app creates different answers (radio buttons) to select based on what I have in arrays, but I can't figure out how to change the font of these answers. Usually I would just change the font in the layout.xml file, but I only have the radio group there, not the actual buttons.

Here is my code:

```
    private void createRadioButton(View view) {
    RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

    String[] answers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.question_1_answers);
    for (int i=0;i<answers.length;i++){
        String answer = answers[i];
        RadioButton button = new RadioButton(getActivity());
        button.setText(answer);
        group.addView(button);
    }
}
```

I wanted to do something like this:

```
Typeface typeface = getResources().getFont(R.font.myfont);
button.setTypeface(typeface);
```

but that requires API 26 and I'm working with API 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this :

```
RadioButton rb  = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radiobutton);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "MyFont.ttf");
rb.setTypeface(font);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `CustomRaioButton` and add it to your view:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class CustomRadioButton extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton {
    public CustomRadioButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    public CustomRadioButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);

    }

    public CustomRadioButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

private void init(Context context) {

        Typeface typeface = getResources().getFont(R.font.myfont);
        setTypeface(typeface);
        a.recycle();

}
}
```